# Why does not using to_number here end up giving me the result twice?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Screenshot of the result

[image]

I first tried making the solution for this exercise without using to_number (lower half of picture) since manager_id is a number (I checked it beforehand). However this gives me the result twice. So I looked at the solution that my teacher provided and saw that the teacher uses to_number (upper half of the picture). So I tested that version and it only gives the result once.

Why does this happen?

Below is a screenshot that shows that manager_id is already a number so why convert it again to_number?

Manager_id is defined as a number

[image]

Thanks in advance

A confused student :)

Comment: Right mouse click on the terminal window header -> Properties -> Quick Edit Mode = selected, Insert mode = selected. Then just select the code inside the terminal window and press `Enter` key. It will copy the selected code to the clipboard. It is much better than [screenshot of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557), because [it is not reusable](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: Oh thanks, didn't know about that feature. Will use this if I ever have another question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a slash `/` character somewhere in the afiedt.buf file? If so, it "instructs" SQL*Plus to re-run the last statement and you got the result twice.

Because, `TO_NUMBER` has nothing to do with two "results". These aren't two rows (returned by the same query), but the same query ran twice.

Something like this:

```
SQL> select count(*) from emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL> /              --> this

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL>
```

---

Or, even better: contents of my `a.sql` file:

```
prompt Number of rows in EMP table

select count(*) from emp;
/
```

Note the last slash. When executed, it result in

```
SQL> @a
Number of rows in EMP table

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14


  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot that / did that.
There was indeed an / in the file and after deleting it, I only got the result once.

Comment: There is always a `/` in afiedt.buf, because EDIT without a filename creates its default file from the current SQL buffer with `/` added to the end. The issue here was a stray `;`